# How to use dynamic textview from json in android

Tags: android, json, android-layout, android-intent, textview

I am using post method to get this array and number of columns will increase based on every post.

```
"floor":
[
     {"no_of_bedroom":"1.5","floor_plotsize_start":"692.00","floor_price_start":"4356832.00"},
     {"no_of_bedroom":"2.0","floor_plotsize_start":"1000.00","floor_price_start":"6296000.00"},
     {"no_of_bedroom":"2.0","floor_plotsize_start":"1029.00","floor_price_start":"6478584.00"},
     {"no_of_bedroom":"2.0","floor_plotsize_start":"1132.00","floor_price_start":"7127072.00"},
     {"no_of_bedroom":"3.0","floor_plotsize_start":"1390.00","floor_price_start":"8751440.00"},
     {"no_of_bedroom":"3.0","floor_plotsize_start":"4901.00","floor_price_start":"40801320.00"}
]
```

How to display by using dynamic textview in android?

```
JSONArray jsonarray;
jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("floor");
{
    //How to proceed by using dynamic textview?
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: @newBee see no of bedrooms. I am using get post method.it's not unique key(no of bedrooms,plotsizestart) . If it's not unique, i can use by creating textviews and display it. But problem is all are unique and moreover number of columns also increase when I post it.

Comment: OK, but my question is have you tried anything to generate dynamic textviews?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can create a listview with textview of the item that you would like to display

My suggestion would be using a loop to get per object and place it inside the listview

peseudo code:

```
for(int i=0; i< jsonarray.size(); i++){
    list.add(jsonarray.getJSONObject(i).getString("no_of_bedroom")); //just an example to check the details of no_of_bedroom key and add it inside the 
}
//using list adapter HERE to display the item the TextView
```

It would be good for you to try it out and update us with more information of how you would like to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create the textviews you want,then you can add them to your main layout and display. Below is a small hint for it:

```
JSONArray jArray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("floor");

for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
{
     TextView textview = new TextView();

     textview.setText(""); //your own text
     textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000")); //your own color

     //And now add this textview to your main layout 
     yourlayout.addView(textview);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
JSONArray jArray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("floor");

for(int i=0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
{
     TextView textview = new TextView(this);

     textview.setText(""); //your own text

        layoutname.addView(textview);
}
```